# Understanding case statement in sas proc sql

Tags: postgresql, sas, case

I am having difficulty in understand this sas code.

```
select
      case    
       when DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK."LIITM"n then   
        DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK."LIITM"n     
      else   
        DM_TURNOVER_TMP_SALES."SDITM"n    
      end as "LIITM"n 
        
      case    
       when DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK."LIMCU"n then   
        DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK."LIMCU"n
```

normally we use sas in sql in condition statment of column but here seems to be diffrent.Please help me in understanding this in postgres term.

Comment: `"<name>"n` is SAS syntax for a name-literal, i.e. a column name. Dot syntax `<table-alias>.<column-name>` is used to select a specific column when two or more tables being joined have the same column name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a query from tables `DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK` and `DM_TURNOVER_TMP_SALES`, 
when `DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK.LIITM` is not missing and non zero, `LIITM` will get the value of `DM_TURNOVER_TMP_STOCK.LIITM`. 
Otherwise, it will get the value of `DM_TURNOVER_TMP_SALES.SDITM`.